# Python version inside Strapi Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-3.8, strapi

I have an app running with strapi/strapi image.
I'm starting the app with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  strapi:
    image: strapi/strapi
    container_name: strapidashboard
    restart:  unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - strapi-app-network
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
    ports:
      - '${PORT}:${PORT}'

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodashboard
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - strapi-app-network
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - '${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}'

networks:
  strapi-app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And I have the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.726.0",
    "strapi": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-admin": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-documentation": "^3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-provider-email-sendgrid": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-utils": "3.6.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "32f580f3-9a2b-4050-a2e9-d2dbb5946a5b"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I run it with

> docker-compose up

Then I enter to docker container with:

> sudo docker exec -it strapidashboard /bin/bash

Inside the container, I check python version and the result is:

> Python 3.5.3

The problem is I need python 3.8 to run my code. And I can't find a way to change it over that docker-compose. I'm also using the latest version of strapi.

Any ideas? Maybe I'll can do that using Dockerfile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> using the latest version of strapi

Are you sure about that? Latest version seems to be v4, and the container documentation mentions Strapi v3.

You can look at the [Docker image tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/strapi/strapi/tags), you notice

1. The image hasn't been updated in over a year
2. There is no 3.x tag larger than 3.6

Compose just orchestrates containers, not manages software application versions within the containers...

So, your options are

1. build your own image, then install a later Python version yourself into it
2. [Open a issue / PR](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker) or [follow the existing one](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/issues/321)